# Is there any alternative to using webservices without the premium plan?

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I want to get an updated exchange rate every day to my powerapps app, but microsoft apparently changed the HTTP flow connector to premium, and custom connectors are now premium aswell.

I tried using excel =WEBSERVICE and then importing the data but I cant refresh the excel file automatically, and refreshing it every morning manually is not an option.

Did anyone had any alternative way to make REST/SOAP API calls on powerapps?
Thanks!

Comment: This? https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/edfa8fde25644f149448c8d8cff44699/call-a-web-service-from-a-power-app/

Comment: @Dai Wait I'm so confused!

The HTTP connector is stated as premium when you try creating a blank new flow, and it did not even let me run it, but when I create a copy from the template you sent it let's me run it properly without any issues.

How is that possible?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any "Premium" HTTP Connector. Is it listed in the Gallery at all? If so, can you post a link to it?

Comment: @Dai It indeed became premium.
ref:https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/HTTP-connector-displayed-as-Premium-one/td-p/327133
Using the template, it somehow bypassed it though, I honestly have no idea how but it works!